# Function works in local shiny app but returns wrong value when published to a Shiny server

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote a function for my Shiny app that validates whether or not the user inputted a valid URL. If it's valid, it returns true. If invalid, it returns false. When running the app locally, if I input a valid link, the function works and returns TRUE. When run on a live Shiny server, however, the function returns FALSE.

The function exists in a separate R file that is in my main app directory. I access it using:

```
source("PageValidation.R")
```

Here is the function:

```
#Ensures that the link is a valid usgs URL 
#Takes a string argument for a url
#' checkValidCLLink: checks whether or not the usgs link provided is a real link
#' and can be used for scraping.
#' @param url A string value for the url to check.
#' @return Boolean True or False for if the link is valid.
checkValidCLLink <- function(url1){

  if(is.null(url1) || url1 == "" || url.exists(url1) == FALSE || 
     !grepl("usgs",url1) || !grepl("search",url1)){
    return(FALSE)
  }
  else{
    return(TRUE)
  }
}
```

Basically, if the input is null OR if the input is empty OR if the inputted url does not exist OR if it does not contain the word "usgs" OR the word "search", then the function returns false. Otherwise, it's a valid link and returns TRUE.

Is there some reason this would work locally but not when called in a live shiny app? Am I sourcing the file incorrectly?

Edit: Here is where the function is called in the server:

```
 url <- as.character(input$urlinput)


        #Final test case is to make sure it's a searchable  page. If not, show error message.
        if(!checkValidCLLink(url)){

          shinyalert(title = "Whoops!", text = "Looks like that url is not a valid url. Please try another.", type = "error")
          write(paste0(Sys.time(),"     ","Invalid URL entered: ", url),"log.txt",append = T)
        }
```

Comment: are you sure with "craigslist" or is it "usgs"

Comment: Apologies. It should be usgs. I mistyped in my description. I had a previous craigslist project and I accidentally wrote craigslist there. The code is accurate though and should be for "usgs".

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the server just during the function call and verify the value of the URL the function is becoming?

Comment: So I am not sure about how to incorporate what you are asking with the breakpoint just during the function call, but what I can say is that I did try just printing the values of each criteria of the if statement. What I found was that even though all values evaluate to false (both locally and in a live shiny server), the function still evaluates to true.

Comment: can you share the code of the server?

Comment: Sure, just added the part of the server where this function is called. The server is pretty large so I just shared the part where this is used. I also use this function's output to open up a conditional panel in the UI, but the function fails there as well and does not open the panel. Again, that part also works locally, just not on a live shiny server.